# Aligning the <ul> tag horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an admin panel but I'm having issues with my `ul` tag which is not aligning in a way I want it, its coming vertically instead of horizontally.
I've tried to check some solutions here but they don't seem to work. Here is my `ul` tag **html** code :

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <h2 align="center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> WELCOME ADMIN</h2>
   <ul class="dash">
      <li>
         <a href="calendar.php" title="Report" class="tip" data-placement="bottom" >
         <img src="images/icons/report.png" alt="" />
         <span>Report</span>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="view.php" title="Customers" class="tip" data-placement="bottom" >
         <img src="images/icons/customers.png" alt="" />
         <span>Customers</span>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="insert.php" title="Add Customers" class="tip" data-placement="bottom" >
         <img src="images/icons/add_customer.png" alt="" />
         <span>Add Customers</span>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="member.php" title="Users" class="tip" data-placement="bottom" >
         <img src="images/icons/users.png" alt="" />
         <span>Users</span>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="register3.php" title="Add User" class="tip" data-placement="bottom" >
         <img src="images/icons/add_user.png" alt="" />
         <span>Add User</span>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

My **css** code :

```
ul.dash {
    margin: 20px;
    display:block;
}

ul.dash li {
    float:center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 15px 15px 0;
}

ul.dash li a {
    display:block;
    width:106px;
    height:102px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.dash li a img {
    display:inline;
    width:48px;
    margin-center:0px;
    margin-top:20px;
}

ul.dash li a span {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:11px;
}

ul.dash li a {
     color:#000;
 background:url('../images/icons/largebut.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}


ul.dash li a:hover {
 background:url('../images/icons/largebut_hover.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can go about, will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: ul.dash li {
    float:center; 

to

ul.dash li {
    display:inline-block;

Current there is no value as "center" for float property..u can use text-align:center; for that purpose..if you intended to align center content..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `white-space: nowrap` so that the items don't break vertically.

```
ul.dash {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.dash li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2m01hckp/3/**

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS

```
ul.dash {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
```

Check [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zf1nzvkL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
ul.dash {
        margin: 20px;
        display:block;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        margin-left:0;
        padding-left:0;

    }

    ul.dash li {
        float:center;
        display:inline-block;
        margin:0 15px 15px 0;
    }


    ul.dash li a {
        display:block;
        width:106px;
        height:102px;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    ul.dash li a img {
        display:inline;
        width:48px;
        margin-center:0px;
        margin-top:20px;
    }

    ul.dash li a span {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:10px;
        font-size:11px;
    }
    ul.dash li a {
         color:#000;
     background:url('../images/icons/largebut.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    }


    ul.dash li a:hover {
     background:url('../images/icons/largebut_hover.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/3eygbgze/)